# VSTS add argument to dotnet pack command

Tags: nuget, azure-devops

I'm trying publish a nuget package through **dotnet pack** command including source code in VSTS. 
I can't find how to add '**--include-source**' argument (or any argument) in this picture.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should use `custom` instead of `pack` and then supply *pack* and *--include-source* in the arguments.

Comment: if I change the command to `custom` then `Configuration to Package` and `Package Folder` inputs are gone.

Comment: @albert: Yes, I suppose you need to add those as command line parameters also. I haven't tried my self, I just heard it's the way to do it ;-)

Comment: thanks, it worked. Custom command and   `--include-source --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` arguments

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question, but now you can `--include-source` directly from the task properties

[image]